# How to get the function name of a regprocedure in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, functions, parameter

I'm trying to write a function to get the name of the function associated with a given `regprocedure` variable, as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_funcname(_fn regprocedure)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
  SELECT proname::text
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc AS p
  JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS ns
    ON p.pronamespace = ns.oid
  WHERE p.oid = _fn;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

I expect to get `my_func` in return for

```
SELECT get_funcname('my_func(text, variadic text[])');
```

However, the above is giving me the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "variadic"
LINE 1: SELECT get_funcname('my_func(text, variadic text[])');
                                ^
CONTEXT:  invalid type name "variadic text[]"
```

Can anyone help explain how to fix the function or syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "variadic"
```

From [the docs,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS)

> `VARIADIC` parameters are input parameters, but are treated specially as described next.

That means you don't do anything special for `VARIADIC` parameters beyond what you would otherwise specify for input params. In your case, just drop that token,

```
SELECT get_funcname('my_func(text, text[])');
```

> Can anyone help explain how to fix the function or syntax?

Sure.

```
WHERE p.oid = regexp_replace(_fn, ' VARIADIC ', ' ', 'i');
```